# Identify part orientation

Tags: pcb, switches, components

I have a part that looks like this under my microscope:

[image]

and it is a TPS22810 load switch ([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps22810.pdf)). But, how do I know which side is which?

Comment: According to page 3, there is a dot, or an indentation above pin 1. Can you see or feel one?

Comment: Feel? I can barely feel the part :-D And not even under the microscope I can see something, see picture...

Comment: You might also be able to measure the body diode in the MOSFET between pins 1 and 6 (the 2 end pins), see page 15.

Comment: I would tend to think pin 1 is the bottom left, but I can't find anything in the datasheet showing how the 19HF is oriented to confirm that.  The vertical may be showing where the pin 1/6 end is.

Comment: Usually when you orient the component so that you're looking at the top of it with the text right-side up, pin 1 is in the bottom left-hand corner.

Comment: thank you! Diode means, only in one direction there'd be a current flow, correct?

Comment: @RaphaelJeger Use the diode function on a multimeter.

Comment: Yes. From 6 to 1.

Comment: There is a very faint dot in the lower left corner. It might get more visible if the light angle is changed, but anyway the photo looks a bit grainy and blurry as it is quite dark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vertical bar on the left hand side of the part indicates the orientation. Therefore the pin 1 is located on the bottom left corner, and the pin 3 in the bottom right corner.

The text is always readable when the pin 1 is on the bottom left corner

The sequence is as follows:

### 6 5 4

### 1 2 3

Comment: Thank you! Why don't they write that as-is in the diagram? :-D

Comment: "The text is always readable when the pin 1 is on the bottom left corner" just wanted to point out that this isn't true for all parts, just in case people thought it was